# DJI SDK: Pause/Resume Waypoint mission when arriving on point?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I haven't found any info on this. I'd like to build a waypoint mission like this:

1. drone arrives at waypoint
2. whole mission pauses, notifies the user (is there a listener for waypoints?)
3. app goes to another activity to take photo
4. user comes back from photo activity
5. user presses button, mission continues to next waypoint.

I see the waypoint actions but it's not exactly what I'd like to achieve. I'd like to let the user control the mission manually, but have the option to do things like skip waypoints, but also to go to another activity while the drone is waiting at a waypoint.

Any tips on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer pertains specifically to the android SDK, but similar concepts exist for the iOS SDK as well.

In Android, waypoint missions are created and controlled through the [WaypointMissionOperator](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypointMissionOperator.html) class.  Instances of this class allow for setting a listener through the `addListener` method that will be called when updated aircraft state is available.  The `onExecutionUpdate` method of the `WaypointMissionOperatorListener` that you pass to that method will receive a [WaypointMissionExecutionEvent](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypointMissionExecutionEvent.html).  This object has a `getProgress` method which will give you information on the state of the mission that you need (
`targetWaypointIndex` and `isWaypointReached`).

To pause the mission at a specific waypoint, you may want to add a hold at the waypoint.  This allows your software running on the mobile device time to detect that the aircraft has reached the waypoint and send a mission pause command.

The rest of your question gets into a bit of design philosophy which is a bit out of scope for stackoverflow, but feel free to contact me directly.